# Python - XML Parsing not working with nested for loops

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am currently creating a system that asks for a couple of words, then replaces it if a synonym of the word is found in the XML file.

Here's the code:

```
def wordproc(self, word):

    lmtzr = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(word)
    tokens_lemma = [lmtzr.lemmatize(tokens) for tokens in tokens]
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    chunking = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)


    important_words = []
    unimportant_tags = ['MD', 'TO', 'DT', 'JJR', 'CC', 'VBZ']

    for x in chunking:

        if x[1] not in unimportant_tags:
            important_words.append(x[0])

    print(important_words)
    self.words = (important_words)
    print(self.words)
    self.loop = len(self.words)
    self.xmlparse(self.words, self.loop)

def xmlparse(self, words, loops):

    root = ElementTree.parse('data/word-test.xml').getroot()
    for i in range(loops):
        syn_loc = [word for word in root.findall('word') if word.findtext('mainword') == words]
        for nym in syn_loc:
            print(nym.attrib)
            word_loop = self.loop
            new_word = (nym.findtext('synonym'))
            words = new_word
    print(words)
    vf = videoPlay()
    vf.moviepy(words)
```

When the words from wordproc is sent to the xmlparse function, it doesn't work. Any guidance? Or am i missing a crucial point? Any help would be great!

EDIT : Here's a short XML file

```
<synwords>
<word>
    <mainword>affection</mainword>
    <wordtag>N</wordtag>
    <synonym>love</synonym>
</word>
<word>
    <mainword>sweetie</mainword>
    <wordtag>N</wordtag>
    <synonym>love</synonym>
</word>
<word>
    <mainword>appreciation</mainword>
    <wordtag>N</wordtag>
    <synonym>love</synonym>
</word>
<word>
    <mainword>beloved</mainword>
    <wordtag>N</wordtag>
    <synonym>love</synonym>
</word>
<word>
    <mainword>emotion</mainword>
    <wordtag>N</wordtag>
    <synonym>love</synonym>
</word>
```

And my desired results :

```
words = ["beloved", "sweetie","affection"]
```

the results, after comparing to the XML, will then be

```
words = ["love", "love", "love"]
```

Comment: could you show a simple xml and what's the result you are expecting?

Comment: Done, i have added a small XML sample and a desired result

Comment: still it's being unclear, you have posted a code where many functions use is not clear to us, also try to mention what are you going to pass and what you want to get, to be; it's unclear with your statements- your desire output is in list but you want to replace it but where? in xml or at runtime?

Comment: i am going to pass a list with words(from an input box), and the desired result is, the words inside the list would be replaced by the new words from the XML file. Runtime, i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for word in xml and parse it every time I suggest you can map your word and synonym in python dictionary and then you can very easily lookup or manipulate as you desire. I have use beautifulsoup to parse xml below:

```
xml = """<synwords>
<word>
    <mainword>affection</mainword>
    <wordtag>N</wordtag>
    <synonym>love</synonym>
</word>

.
.
.

<synwords>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "html.parser")  # xml is your xml content
words = soup.find_all('word')
mapped_dict = {word.find("mainword").text: word.find("synonym").text for word in words}
print(mapped_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'sweetie': 'love', 'beloved': 'love', 'appreciation': 'love', 'affection': 'love', 'emotion': 'love'}
```

Comment: can the xml variable be replaced with the XML file that i was using? It is one of the important things that is supposed to be used.

Comment: yes you can read file and store content of file in any variable you want

Comment: Okay thanks! Ill search on how to parse the file. Thank you so much!

Comment: One last thing, what is the result of the mapped_dict above? I am confused

Comment: check the answer I have added output of print statement

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to just replace the words with the result? Like, instead of 'sweetie': 'love', it'll be just "love", something like that?

Comment: you can use dictionary attributes if you are to filter with lookup work (which is key in here) or directly use list comprehension instead of dict comprehension

Comment: Thank you! Ill try this now